# Find row when Cumulative sum reaches certain value with condition #2

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This question is based on the answer provided in the thread linked below. I have the same question byt my data is ordered a bit different.

[Find row when Cumulative sum reaches certain value with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53591983/find-row-when-cumulative-sum-reaches-certain-value-with-condition/56950713#56950713)

In sheet1 I have columns ID, COST and Profitability Date. (ABC)
[image: Screenshot1]

In sheet2 I have a date row (ex 201801) running horizontally starting in B1 (B1,C1 etc..). Starting in A2 i have the different ID's running vertically. The Revenue for each ID follows beneath the date row.
[image: Screenshot2]

**I would like to have the formula in Profitability Date (sheet1 column C) to return the date (sheet2 row 1) when the cost (sheet1 column B) is >= than the revenue in sheet2.**

Comment: I would do a helper table and calculate the cumulative values for each date. So for row 2 the cumulative value for 201802 and 201803 would be the same... Then the search becomes easy while the logic is shown in your linked question and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the following array formula in C2, confirm with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER, and copy down:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$J$1,MATCH(TRUE,SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$J$4,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4,0),0),,,,COLUMN(Sheet2!$B$1:$J$1)-COLUMN(Sheet2!$B$1)+1))>=B2,0))
```